# Best color for one image

Tags: color-theory

I have an application with two columns, one on the left that display the major information, one on the right with a random image (and a bit of text).

I would like to use a background color (a subtle gradient) for the left column that looks good with the image on the right.

However I have no education in the graphic world and have no idea on the techniques to use to find that best color. Ideally this "technique" must be done programmatically so that my app give good results for any image.

Could you give me some name or other things that I can search for ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, is using a javascript library like "Vibrant.js" what you're looking for? You would also have to find a way to code the text color to work based on the background color that was picked.

Comment: Only sure fire option.. greys....

Answer (score 2):

**Any** background color **will** alter the [visual perception](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3823087/) ([2](https://www.designmatrix.com/pl/cyberpl/cic.html)) of any nearby image. In broad, general terms -- nearby color makes *that* color *seem* more prominent in any image, even though the image hasn't changed.

The *only* option to retain the correct visual perception of an image is to use a **neutral grey** background. That way, the background does not influence the image visually.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. Howvere I do not really care about the perception of the image which is only a visual thing (and space filler). I only want to have a something that looks good (but not always the same color).